# the requested resource () is not available tomcat

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-404, tomcat6

When i compile and deploy it in localhost it works fine. But when i create the war file and deploy it in another server it pops the error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /IJPWeb/index.jsp
type Status report
message /IJPWeb/index.jsp
description The requested resource (/IJPWeb/index.jsp) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.24
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>IJPWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here is one error appear in catalina.out

> javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Cannot create object name for org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector@5a199939java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.Inet4Address cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I do not have any servlet classes. I call some Java methods from my JSP (index.jsp). Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you check that the war file contains the index.jsp file ? How did you create the war ?

Comment: yes. When i deploy war in tomcat it created all the files and folders. everything is there

Comment: Try running `localhost:8080`. Can you see tomcat  welcome page ?

Comment: It works in localhost (Windows). When i deploy it in a remoter server it do not work. But tomcat works in that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check both Tomcat version are same on your local and remote location.

Also verify that Java version which compiled the web application on local is compatible with remote your tomcat's JRE.